# ASP.Net Core - Get All data of a post form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, arraylist, multidimensional-array, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to save all data of a form.

My form has these elements-

[image]

( Using [Postman Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) )

My controller is like this-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(IFormCollection data)
{
    return Ok(data);
}
```

So, I am getting something like this-

```
[
  {
    "key": "user_id",
    "value": [
      "'12'"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "title",
    "value": [
      "123"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "text[]",
    "value": [
      "werwer",
      "ghj"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get the value of **texts**.

So, for this case-

```
"werwer",
"ghj"
```

So, I have tried something like this-

```
foreach (string description in data["text"])
{
    // description => empty
}
```

and also tried this-

```
data.text
```

and also-

```
data->text
```

But nothing works for me.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not loop through each keys and if the key is "text", get the values. Since the value is a comma seperated string, you can call the `Split` method on that to get an array which contains 2 items( from your sample input).

```
foreach (string description in data.Keys)
{
    if (description.Equals("text"))
    {
        var v = data[description];
        var stringItems = v.Split(',');
        foreach (var stringItem in stringItems)
        {
          //do something with stringItem
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, the key should be `text`, not `text[]`. Even if you have muliple input fields with the same name "text", when you submit, It will be a single key (`"text"`) with 2 items int he value property

```
{
    "key": "text",
    "value": [
      "werwer",
      "ghj"
    ]
  }
```